# BigQuery | Python | Export data from BigQuery table VIEW

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

This is a simple code to export from Biq Query to Google storage, in CSV format

```
def export_data():

  client = bigquery.Client()

  project = 'xxxxx'
  dataset_id = 'xxx'
  table_id = 'xxx'
  bucket_name = 'xxx'

  destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'EXPORT_FILE.csv')
  dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
  table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

  extract_job = client.extract_table(
      table_ref,
      destination_uri,
      # Location must match that of the source table.
      location='EU')  # API request
  extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

  print('Exported {}:{}.{} to {}'.format(
      project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri))
```

It works perfectly for general tables, BUT when I try to export data from saved table VIEW, it failed with this error:

```
BadRequest: 400 Using table xxx:xxx.xxx@123456 is not allowed for this operation because of its type. Try using a different table that is of type TABLE.
```

Does exist any way to export data from table view?

What I'm trying to achieve is, to get the data from BigQuery in CSV format, and upload to Google analytics Product Data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BigQuery views [are subject to a few limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro):

- You cannot run a BigQuery job that exports data from a view.

There are more than 10+ other limitations which I didn't posted in the answer as they might change. Follow the [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro) to read all of them.

You need to query your view and write the results to a destination table, and then issue an export job on the destination table.

Comment: No other way around it?

Comment: The answer provided a way around it: "You need to query your view and write the results to a destination table, and then issue an export job on the destination table."

Answer (score 1):

Almost 5 years later, this could be useful for someone with the same problem. A workaround is to query the view and use the temporary table created by BigQuery to export, avoiding the creation and deletion of a staging table.

Code from the original question modified to use the temporary table:

```
def export_data():

  client = bigquery.Client()

  project = 'xxxxx'
  dataset_id = 'xxx'
  view_id = 'xxx'
  bucket_name = 'xxx'

  destination_uri = f'gs://{bucket_name}/EXPORT_FILE.csv'

  query = f"SELECT * FROM `{project}.{dataset_id}.{view_id}`"
  query_job = client.query(query)
  result = query_job.result()
  print(f"Reading {result.total_rows} rows from BigQuery")

  destination = query_job.destination
  destination_table = client.get_table(destination)

  extract_job = client.extract_table(
      destination_table,
      destination_uri,
      # Location must match that of the source table.
      location='EU')  # API request
  extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

  print(f'Exported {project}:{dataset_id}.{table_id} to {destination_uri}')
```

Comment: Is there a way to export data into GCS in a different account?

Comment: If BQ dataset and GCS bucket are in different projects, you just need an account with the right permissions in both projects